# how can I deselect elements after selected them in inkcanavas

Tags: c#, wpf

I select some element in `inkcanvas` like this:

```
List<UIElement> temp = e.GetSelectedElements().ToList();
SelectList.Add(temp.ElementAt(0));
inkcanvas.Select(SelectList);//in this line inckanvas editing mode change to select
```

Now I want to deselect one of them when I click on it, but rectangle `mouseclick` doesn't fire that cant I determine with of element clicked!
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

inkCanvas.Select(null, null); this will do the trick.

Comment: Please expand your answer.